# TypeError: $node->delete() throws RequestContext error when using Symfony Request object

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

During the process of creating unit tests for my Drupal 9 module, I encountered an error while attempting to delete a node using the $node->delete() method. The error message states: "Drupal\Core\Routing\RequestContext::fromRequest(): Argument #1 ($request) must be of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, null given, called in [file path]".

This issue seems to be related to the usage of the Symfony Request object in the Drupal core code. I am specifically facing this error while running unit tests for my module. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully delete nodes within the unit testing environment.

I have included a snippet from the relevant code below

```
interface CrudRepository
{

  ....
  
  /**
   * Deletes the given entity.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $entity
   *   The entity to delete.
   *
   * @return bool
   *   TRUE if the entity was deleted successfully, FALSE otherwise.
   */
  public function delete(NodeInterface $entity);
}

abstract class BaseRepository implements CrudRepository
{
  /**
   * The type of node managed by this repository.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $type;

  /**
   * Sets the node type of this repository.
   *
   * @param string $type
   * The type of node.
   */
  protected abstract function setNodeType($type);
  
  ....

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function delete(NodeInterface $entity)
  {
    try {
      $entity->delete();
      return TRUE;
    } catch (EntityStorageException $e) {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}

class DatacenterRepository extends BaseRepository
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->setNodeType('datacenter');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setNodeType($type)
  {
    $this->type = $type;
  }
}

namespace Drupal\repository_manager\Tests\Unit;

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class DatacenterRepositoryTest.
 *
 * Unit test for the DatacenterRepository class.
 *
 * @group repository_manager
 */
class DatacenterRepositoryTest extends UnitTestCase
{

  /**
   * The DatacenterRepository instance to be tested.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\repository_manager\Repository\DatacenterRepository
   */
  protected $datacenterRepository;

  /**
   * The EntityTypeManagerInterface instance.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * The container instance.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
   */
  protected $container;

  /**
   * Bootstraps Drupal to make necessary services available.
   */
  protected function bootDrupal(): void
  {
    $autoloader = require DRUPAL_ROOT . '/autoload.php';

    // Bootstrap Drupal.
    $kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest(Request::createFromGlobals(), $autoloader, 'dev');
    $kernel->boot();

    // Retrieve the Drupal container.
    $this->container = $kernel->getContainer();

    // Set the Drupal container to the static Drupal class.
    \Drupal::setContainer($this->container);
    $this->entityTypeManager = $this->container->get('entity_type.manager');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp(): void
  {
    parent::setUp();

    // Bootstrap Drupal to make the necessary services available.
    $this->bootDrupal();

    /**
     * The constant indicating a new entity has been saved.
     * This is used to avoid conflicts when mocking entity save operations.
     */
    if (!defined('SAVED_NEW')) {
      define('SAVED_NEW', 1);
    }

    // Create the DatacenterRepository instance.
    $this->datacenterRepository = $this->container->get('repository_manager.repository.datacenter');
  }
  
   ....

  /**
   * Test for deleting a Datacenter entity.
   */
  public function testDelete()
  {
    $title = 'Datacenter ' . uniqid();
    // Create a new Datacenter entity.
    $node = Node::create([
      'type' => 'datacenter',
      'title' => $title,
      // Add other fields as needed.
    ]);
    $node->enforceIsNew();
    $node->save();

    // Delete the entity.
    // TODO: Check the issue with deleting a Node at the BaseRepository level when calling from unit test.
    $result = $this->datacenterRepository->delete($node);

    // Assert that the entity is successfully deleted.
    $this->assertTrue($result);
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on whether the bootDrupal() function is necessary in this context or if there are alternative approaches to create UnitTestCase classes.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer or is the question difficult or incomprehensible